# date parsing String -> Date

Tags: android, datetime

I have a date (as a String): "Sat, 24 Feb 2018 05:00:00 GMT"
Then I try to convert that value to Date object like this:

```
open fun toDate(timestamp: String) : Date {
        val data = dateFormat.parse(timestamp)
        Log.d(TAG, "timestamp=$timestamp, data=$data")
        return data
    }
```

And the output is

```
timestamp=Sat, 24 Feb 2018 05:00:00 GMT, data=Mon Feb 21 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2101
```

Why output date is messed up?

Update: My datetime format is : *EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss*

Comment: What’s your `dateFormat` format?

Comment: @algrid question is updated

Answer (score 0):

String to Date

```
String dtStart = "2018-02-02T09:27:37Z";  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  

try {  
Date date = format.parse(dtStart);  
System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

you can use this method to get date from a string

```
Date date = stringToDate(date, "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zz yyyy");        

private Date stringToDate(String aDate,String aFormat) {

  if(aDate==null) return null;
  ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
  SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat(aFormat);
  Date stringDate = simpledateformat.parse(aDate, pos);
  return stringDate;            

  }
```

Comment: now i get "timestamp=Wed, 31 Jan 2018 18:00:00 GMT, data=null"